# Paint liquifying around cooker: solution?

Tags: paint

I applied ["One Coat Matt Emulsion" paint](https://goo.gl/WHvhVJ) on my kitchen's wallpaper (can't remove the wallpaper).

When cooking though, the paint in the area around the cooker starts liquifying so that if you swipe a finger it comes wet with a bit of paint (10% paint 90% water maybe).

Should I apply another coat of something? If so, what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet is you used a water-based latex and the wallpaper has some oil in it (being over the stove there's a good chance it absorbed oil over the years). What's happening is the heat and humidity are driving the water back into the paint, and the oil in the wallpaper is interfering with the adhesion.

Two things I would do.

1. Get an oil based primer (like original Kilz). It should help the adhesion of the paint to the wallpaper. Oil based should adhere, regardless of what's in the wallpaper
2. Put a semi-gloss enamel over it (can be water based latex). The "gloss" part of the paint will better resist the water getting into it

Comment: But the paint is already applied. Are you recommending to apply primer on top of the paint?

Comment: You might have to wipe it off. I've not tried a latex -> primer -> enamel sandwich like that. In theory, the primer and enamel should block the moisture from getting to the latex layer

Comment: I think you will have to get off everything you can. If the wallpaper has been exposed to oil, most water-based paints won't stick well, wet or dry.

Comment: Are you saying I have to remove the paint I painfully applied for days? Is there not any alternative? Why can't I protect this paint with additional layers of products such as those mentioned in this answer? Could it work?

Comment: @drake035 This is where you get to make a decision. You don't need our permission to do this. Just understand that by not removing the old paint you run the risk that you still have a problem of the paint coming off. The only thing you're risking here is the money for the paint and your time. That's your call. I'd leave a comment either way, so future people looking for this type of help know how it went.

Comment: @Machavity: I just checked, it's not a latex paint. It's just a regular, matt paint. Low VOC (0.30-7.99%). Contains 1,2-benzisothiazol-3(2H)-one. No more info on the tin. Do you still think it's worth applying these 2 layers you recommended? If not then what would you advise?

Comment: I'm no paint expert, but the stuff you mentioned is a preservative, so I don't think you can say it's not a latex. If you cleaned it up with water it's latex. Otherwise you'd need mineral spirits

Comment: I don't think it's latex because (1) there's no mention of "latex" anywhere on the tin and (2) I understand latex has a very strong smell and requires to open windows a lot yet the paint I used has almost no smell at all.. Thanks for the input though :)

Comment: @drake035: 1) Your link suggests you are in UK, note that US based answerers are likely using USA terms not UK terms. They differ. US "Latex" is approximately the same as UK "Emulsion".  2) There exists "bathroom and kitchen" emulsion paint that is intended for areas of high humidity.

Comment: Wow thanks @RedGrittyBrick, that all makes sense now! Would you second Machavity in his suggestion that applying oil-based primer then enamel on top of the paint would fix problem?